# Make the cursor stop at the last character of a line instead of the newline character

Tags: cursor, newlines, motion

How to make cursor stop at the last character of a line instead of at the linefeed character? I use evil-mode.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Start Emacs in shell via `emacs -nw -Q`.
- Press <kbd>C-e</kbd> to move focus to the end of the line.
- You can see the yellow cursor stops at the linefeed character instead of the `{` character.

[image: Example screenshot]

UPDATE:
Thanks guys. It turns out it's not a bug but just default behavior of Emacs.

My issue is actually I'm using evil-mode and I mistakenly turn off a useful feature of evil.

Here is the CORRECT setup code to turn that flag on in evil-mode:

```
(setq evil-move-cursor-back t)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>(This is too long for a comment, and while not literally an answer, I hope it might help the OP.)</sub>

While Drew's answer covers what you literally *want*, this is probably not what you *need*.  [Point](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Point.html) in Emacs is never *on* a character, it is *between* characters:

> Like other positions, point designates a place between two characters
>   (or before the first character, or after the last character), rather
>   than a particular character. Usually terminals display the cursor over
>   the character that immediately follows point; point is actually before
>   the character on which the cursor sits.

Of course, both the display *and* some commands might mislead you.  For instance, [`what-cursor-position`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Position-Info.html)

> shows information about the current cursor position and the buffer
>   contents at that position [...] After `Char:`, this shows the
>   character in the buffer at point.

I am not sure whether the wording "at that position" and "at point" in this excerpt are bugs in the manual or not; I would consider reporting them with e.g. `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Possibly related tip: `(setq-default cursor-type 'bar)` will make the cursor into a vertical bar that's clearly *between* characters.

Answer (score 5):

Bind `C-e` to a command that puts the cursor one char to the left of the line end.

```el
(defun foo (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (end-of-line arg)
  (unless (bolp) (backward-char)))

(global-set-key "\C-e" 'foo)
```

(Although I cannot imagine why you would want to move the cursor there.)